# How to perform a queued task with OmniThreadLibrary

Tags: multithreading, delphi, omnithreadlibrary

Can someone give me some guidance on how to use OmniThreadLibrary to perform a "queued" task. Could be anything, but in this question let me use the example of sending 100 emails. I want to only be using 3 threads at a time.

How do I queue the sending of emails?

How do I get notified when 1 thread is finished and ready to receive the next email/task?

How do I get the result of the email send? (i.e. OK, or an error occurred).

I have seen some very short examples of using OTL, but I need something a bit more comprehensive, to understand how to perform the above.

Can someone explain how to do the above or point me to an example that covers something similar.

Thanks

Comment: http://otl.17slon.com/tutorials.htm

Comment: Looks like you need an OTL Pipeline - it would consume the Queue of mails to send and it would produce the Queue of "result of the email send"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
@ Arioch: Yes, it looks like you are on the right track. I found this link which is quite close to what I am looking for: http://otl.17slon.com/book/doku.php?id=book:howto:webdownload. Quite a bit of stuff to get used to.